# What's the best practice - Headless UI Modals inside loop - React.js

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I've just started my React journey a month ago,
I got a question (I migth sound stupid), It's in my head from past 2-3 days.

#### The Question:

Suppose we have a table with list of Super-heros, and each row contains a Edit button, clicking that opens a `Headless UI` Modal with a Edit form.

Now my concern is,
Should I put the Modal inside of the Super-heros loop, or create the Modal along with a State outside of the loop.
And we'll update the state from within the loop to open/close the outside modal.
Which would be considered as good practice and also good for performance.

#### My Thought:

I think how Headless UI's modals work like: whenever the modal get's opened then only it get's rendered to the DOM.
So having the Modal components inside of loop shouldn't matter.

---

I don't need help with the code, just giving some explanation is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create the dialog component in different file:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Dialog } from '@headlessui/react'

export default function MyDialog(props) {
  const {isOpen, selectedItem, handleClose} = props
  return (
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={handleClose}>
      <Dialog.Panel>
       
        ... YOUR UPDATE FORM 

        <button onClick={() => {
         // YOUR UPDATE LOGIC 
         //NOTE : YOU HAVE THE SELECTED ITEM
         handleClose();
        }}>Update</button>
        <button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</button>
      </Dialog.Panel>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

Now form the page in which you will display your table :

```
import MyDialog from "../";
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState({});
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);

// your logic

return (
  <>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Hero name</th>
        <th>Edit Hero</th>
      </tr>
      {heros.map((hero) => (
        <tr key={hero.id}>
          <td>hero.name</td>
          <td>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedItem(hero);
                setOpenDialog(true);
              }}
            >
              edit
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>

    <MyDialog
      isOpen={openDialog}
      selectedItem={selectedItem}
      handleClose={() => {
        setOpenDialog(false);
        setSelectedItem({});
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```

Each time you click the button, the page component will re-render with `selectedItem = the_selected_item` and `isOpen = true` so `MyDialog` component is open and receive the `selectedItem` you update your item there inside it then you close it

Comment: Basically, I should keep a state outside the loop to keep track of what to edit, and update the state from within the loop, but still updating that state of parent component will cause every child component (items of loop) to re-render? isn't it?

Comment: yes you are correct that's why you need the model outside the loop to render only once maybe when you put it inside the loop you will avoid this extra render but think about the parent component when it renders

Comment: Both ways, I don't see much difference.
Since, having the state outside of loop, updating that state will re-render every child, that also doesn't seem very good in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to keep the modal outside the loop and open/close it based on the state in the parent component. Now to avoid rerendering of all the list items again when there is a change which could be easily done by memoizing list item component, it will solve the performance issue.